# ndb.OR makes query costs more

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Using AppEngine appstats I profiled my queries, and noticed that although the docs say a query costs one read, queries using ndb.OR (or .IN which expands to OR), cost n reads (n equals the number of OR clauses).

eg:

```
votes = (Vote.query(ndb.OR(Vote.object == keys[0], Vote.object == keys[1]))
     .filter(Vote.user_id == user_id)
     .fetch(keys_only=True))
```

This query costs 2 reads (it matches 0 entities). If I replace the ndb.OR with Vote.object.IN, the number of reads equals the length of array I pass to read.

This behavior is kind of contradicts the docs.

I was wondering if anyone else experienced the same, and if this is a bug in AE, docs, or my understanding.

Thanks.

Comment: It's a problem with your understanding. The cost for a query is for a basic query.  Read up on how it performs OR and IN, and you will see it creates multiple queries then merge's the data, hence multiple query costs.

Comment: Thanks.
I was actually trying to find something mentioning something like this but couldn't find anything.

Comment: It's not particularly explicit in the docs, but if you read the ndb query docs it is in there (sort of ;-) have another read of https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query docs for ndb are not particularly explicit but this paragraph is your best answer

> In addition to the native operators, the API supports the != operator,
>   combining groups of filters using the Boolean OR operation, and the IN
>   operation, which test for equality to one of a list of possible values
>   (like Python's 'in' operator). These operations don't map 1:1 to the
>   Datastore's native operations; thus they are a little quirky and slow,
>   relatively. They are implemented using in-memory merging of result
>   streams. Note that p != v is implemented as "p < v OR p > v". (This
>   matters for repeated properties.)

In this doc https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries

Comment: Yeah...
I consider this a bug in the document and not in my understanding :).
I would expect the docs to be clear about something this important.

Comment: BTW, considering this, if I just want to check for entity existence (assuming I have some criteria to query by and the possible keys), is there a way to do it without paying for each check? I used get_multi() but that costs a read for non-existing entities as well, and the query approach requires an IN operation. I was wondering if there's another way...

Comment: If you have the keys, the fastest will be the get_multi, as to your read count, I would test/profile the alternatives. The other is a projection query, which only returns values from the index, so no secondary fetch required, if that satisfies your requirements.

Comment: get_multi is one cost per key, whether it exists or not.
A query will be AT LEAST one cost per potential item (due to what you explained). So I think get_multi is better, unless I missed something.