# objectify v6 - NOT and IN filters no longer supported? Alternatives?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

The objectify v6 docs say:

> NOT and IN filters are not supported by the new SDK. You will get a
>   runtime error if you try to
>   ofy().load().type(Thing.class).filter("field !=", value) or
>   filter("field IN" values).

Even if in objectify v5, should we stay away from using NOT or IN filters as they are, it looks like, on the way out?

Is there anymore information on why these are no longer supported? Any alternative methods to maybe achieve a similar type of query? Specifically, the IN query. Which is/was pretty useful if you have say a list of user id's that you need to query all of something of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those were just convenience filters anyway that got translated into a composition of other filters.

> The != (not-equal) and IN (membership) operations are implemented by
>   combining other filters using the OR operation. The first of these,

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#neq_and_in

`property != value` is implemented as `(property < value) OR (property > value)`

`property IN [value1, value2, ...]` is implemented as `(property == value1) OR (property == value2) OR ...`

So you could just convert all your `!=` and `IN` filters to that

Comment: What is the performance of `(property == value1) OR (property == value2) OR ...` as the number of values being searched grows? Any idea?

Comment: I haven't tested it out personally, but I would imagine that performance would start to degrade. It definitely would have to do more work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323886/ndb-or-makes-query-costs-more I would consider reformatting your data a bit to better support the query you are trying to do. Like use a computed property to group records into larger category-buckets